# What does blue-colored text mean in the terminal output from the Django development server?

Tags: django

Sometimes the lines after each normal terminal-green colored line like '[24/Sep/2012 00:42:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1904' are my normal terminal-green color, and sometimes they are blue. I am getting a change in the display of my webpages that does not exactly follow the changes in blue / green output, but I was thinking knowing what the changing color of the output means may give me a clue as to what is going on.

Comment: So I noticed that the lines that are blue all end with '304 0' whereas the lines that are normal color end with '200' followed by another varying number which I assume corresponds to the number of bytes in the file that was served ...

Comment: The numbers 200 and 304 are HTTP response codes. Different colors help in picking out responses that are not 2XX (success).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, blue ones are being picked from cache.

**EDIT:**

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes):

*304 Not Modified*

Indicates the resource has not been modified since last requested.[2] Typically, the HTTP client provides a header like the If-Modified-Since header to provide a time against which to compare. Using this saves bandwidth and reprocessing on both the server and client, as only the header data must be sent and received in comparison to the entirety of the page being re-processed by the server, then sent again using more bandwidth of the server and client.